# Angular and firebase - Cannot Map of undefined on first load

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

It works after the first load, I need to know how to provide a promise to prevent the data mapping without first letting it load. On first load of the site it displays the error below. I think it's cause by not allowing the colleciton of data from the database before trying to map it?

Console error

> DashboardComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at DashboardComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts.DashboardComponent.populateDashboard (dashboard.component.ts:70) at

For context the line 70 is this.goalsLength e.g. the first line that calls the db.

The TS file

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.populateDashboard();
  }

  populateDashboard() {
    // just needs a filter on active = if active its not completed. CHANGE IN DB FROM ACTIVE TO COMPLETED
    this.goalsLength = this.progressService.getActiveGoals().map(goals => {
      return goals.length;
    });

    this.visionsLength = this.progressService.getCompletedVisions().map(visions => {
      return visions.length;
    });

    this.opportunitiesLength = this.progressService.getCompletedOpportunities().map(opportunities => {
      return opportunities.length;
    });

    this.actionPlansLength = this.progressService.getCompletedActionPlans().map(actionPlans => {
      return actionPlans.length;
    });
```

Service

```
userId: string;
  completedVisions: FirebaseListObservable<VisionItem[]> = null;
  activeGoals: FirebaseListObservable<Goal[]> = null;
  opportunities: FirebaseListObservable<Goal[]> = null;
  actionPlans: FirebaseListObservable<Goal[]> = null;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase,
              private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    // setting userId returned from auth state to the userId on the service, now we can query
    // currently logged in user, using the id. IMPORTANT
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userId = user.uid
      }
    });
  }

  // Used to get the dashboard values.
  getCompletedVisions(): FirebaseListObservable<VisionItem[]> {
    if (!this.userId) { return; } // if undefined return null.
    this.completedVisions = this.db.list(`visions/${this.userId}`, {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'completed',
        equalTo: true
      }
    });
    return this.completedVisions;
  }

  getCompletedOpportunities(): FirebaseListObservable<Goal[]> {
    if (!this.userId) { return }; // if undefined return null.
    this.opportunities = this.db.list(`goals/${this.userId}`, {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'opportunitiesCompleted',
        equalTo: true
      }
    });
    return this.opportunities;
  }

  getCompletedActionPlans(): FirebaseListObservable<Goal[]> {
    if (!this.userId) { return }; // if undefined return null.
    this.actionPlans = this.db.list(`goals/${this.userId}`, {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'allActionPlanFieldsCompleted',
        equalTo: true
      }
    });
    return this.actionPlans;
  }



     // Dashboard related queries.
      getActiveGoals(): FirebaseListObservable<Goal[]> {
        if (!this.userId) { return }; // if undefined return null.
        this.activeGoals = this.db.list(`goals/${this.userId}`, {
          query: {
            orderByChild: 'completed',
            equalTo: true
          }
        });
        return this.activeGoals;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error messages state, you are willing to return `FirebaseListObservable` from all service functions and subscribing them from component, but service functions will **return `null` when `this.userId` doesn't exist or unsetted**.

The reason this happened is because you are setting `this.userId` in an asynchronous way(`this.afAuth.authState.subscribe`).

Just be sure all branches return `Observable`, for example:

```
if (!this.userId) { return Observable.of([]); }   // provide an empty array if userId is not yet ready
```

Comment: thanks for the response, is there a better way to set the userId? they cant access the page without signing in anyway and I don't want it to load an empty observable as it displays data...

Comment: @user2797454 from your code snippet, you are just getting `length` of result, you can check whether the response is null or not and then set the length to be 0 or real length.

Comment: @user2797454 And if your response is actually **array**(should be `Observable.of([])`), you can return an empty array if `userId` is not yet ready.

Comment: So you mean just wrap each response in an if statement or the whole section and just check each of them in one if?

Comment: @user2797454 sorry, just left a few minutes.  You can change to provide an empty array if userId isn't ready yet.  see my updated answer. This way you don't have to check whether the response is null or not.